# What's the formal functional name for recursive SelectMany?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, naming-conventions, naming

Let's say I have a function with the following signature:

```
IEnumerable<TSource> SelectManyRecursive<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> enumerable,
    Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TSource>> selector
);
```

What would be the name for that if it was implemented in a language such as Scala or Haskell (or even JavaScript since it shares some of common naming)?
(similar how `Select` = `map`, `Where` = `filter` etc)

If it would be a composition of other functions -- which ones?

Comment: `SelectMany` ~ `flatMap` (although this is usually not recursive). Perhaps just `flatten`? That's the terminology I use in my code, anyway: i.e `IEnumerable<Node> FlattenNodes(Tree<Node> nodes)`.

Comment: I tend to think of this operation as a tree traversal. Thus I have a static class Traverse with methods Along(T, Func<T, T>), BreadthFirst(T, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>>), and DepthFirst(T, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>>). For the function you describe, I would just do .SelectMany(t => Traverse.[Breadth|Depth]First(x, x => ...))